# Powershell new-item directory with a parameter as part of folder name

Tags: powershell

I'd like to create a folder based on a parameter used in the name, so for example:

```
    $Website = "test"
    new-item \\172.1.1.1\C`$\Folder\$Website_Archive -type directory
```

The _Archive needs to be part of the folder name but I cannot figure out how to pass the $Website with the _Archive included.

Here is the error I get:

New-Item : Item with specified name \172.1.1.1\C$\Folder\ already exists.
At line:2 char:9
+ new-item <<<<  \172.1.1.1\C`$\Folder\$Website_Archive -type directory
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceExists: (\172.1.1.1\C\Folder\:String) [New-Item], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DirectoryExist,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewItemCommand

If I remove the '_Archive' from the line it will create the folder named "test".  I'm assuming it's looking for a parameter of $Website_Archive and not finding it so it tries to just recreate the root folder.  How can I get the parameter passed into the folder name?

Thanks!

BB

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just escape the underscore with a backtick

```
new-item "\\17.1.1.1\C`$\Folder\$Website`_Archive" -type directory
```

Answer (score 4):

Apart from what @JohnL mentions, I prefer string formatting, especially when many variables are involved:

```
"\\172.1.1.1\C`$\Folder\{0}_Archive" -f $Website
```

Comment: Is there a benefit to this method besides clarity?

Comment: @JNK In this case, clarity. But it is meant for constructing string as you might know.

Comment: I do realize it, but didn't know if there was a reason to prefer it over in-line concatenation with doublequotes.  I find that much easier to read normally.

Comment: @JNK - Oh you mean `"abcd" + $blah + "xyz"` vs `"abcd{0}xyz" -f $blah` - the latter will consume less memory ( at least when you are doing many concatenationse. Since strings are immutable in .Net.

Comment: Sorry, I mean `"abcd $blah xyz"` vs `"abcd {0} xyz" -f $blah` since PS automatically converts vars inside doublequotes

Comment: @JNK - Yeah the normal variables are fine, but for properties, compleex names etc, like in this case, I prefer formatting. Helps in refactoring you know.

Comment: @manojlds I like string formatting better as well. For this case I'd prefer to use single quotes so the $ sign doesn't have to be escaped. `'\\172.1.1.1\C$\Folder\{0}_Archive' -f $Website`

Comment: @AndyArismendi - Yes, I didn't even realize that a $ was being escaped in the example :)

Answer (score 3):

Either escape as per JNK's answer, enclose $Website with `$(...)`

```
new-item "\\17.1.1.1\C`$\Folder\$($Website)_Archive" -type directory
```